# Random Module, Inclusive and or Exclusive

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.random) and it says,

> random.**random()**
>   Return the next random floating point number in the range [0.0,
>   1.0).

Are 0.0 and 1.0 inclusive or exclusive?

I'm assuming either `[` or `)` signifies inclusion, whereas the other signifies exclusion, but I'm not sure which is which...

Comment: `[` and `]` conventionally mean inclusive and `(` and `)` conventionally mean exclusive.

Comment: @AndresSalgado so `random()` would return a floating point number between `0.0` and `0.9`?

Comment: Yes, between 0.0 inclusive and 0.99999... (up to the precision allowed by Python).

Comment: @AndresSalgado awesome thanks!!